# Milliseconds in cue file

Tags: c#, datetime, cue-sheet

I am writing an application in C# which generates cue file in order to use in Goldwave.

In my program I'm generating a timestamp. For ex. `Ticks = 77314055`

Later I'm formatting a datetime until milliseconds: `00:07.731`

For testing I'm entering the same value to Goldwave, exporting the cue file and in the cue result is: `00:07:55`

How I should calculate this `55` millisecond value from `731`?

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between the `55` and the `731`. Can you elaborate? And how does the `77314055` relate to `00:07.731`?

Comment: Looks okay, don't do anything.  It just displays the frame number, not msec.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Hidrogenaud](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Cue_sheet), .Cue file's time format is `MM:SS:FF`

" Index points are specified in MM:SS:FF format, and are relative to the start of the file currently referenced. MM is the number of minutes, SS the number of seconds, and FF the number of frames (there are seventy five frames to one second).

You can convert it as `var frames = milliseconds * 0.075;`

Answer (score 0):

Use mod function

```
long tick = 77314055;
long msec = tick % 100;
```